# Docker build from local Dockerfile hangs (Windows 10)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-toolbox

I'm brand new to Docker, and I'm trying to run a Dockerfile on my Windows 10 machine, but it's hanging initially and not doing anything.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox:latest
CMD ["date"]
```

My command from docker

```
$ docker build -f /projects/docker_test .
```

Other things of note:

Docker Toolbox installed on Windows 10 Home edition

Environmental variable:

```
HOME = G:\projects\
```

Dockerfile location:

```
G:\projects\docker_test\Dockerfile
```

File created initially with Notepad.

**EDIT:** I am able to load other docker containers just fine. Docker simply hangs when I try to access a local Dockerfile.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was adding a `.dockerignore` file and add there the folders that are not part of the built image (in my case `/node_modules`).

Answer (score 2):

The -f option is used to specify the path to the Dockerfile.

Try with:

```
docker build -t docker_test -f /projects/docker_test/Dockerfile /projects/docker_test
```

or:

```
cd G:\projects\docker_test\
docker build -t docker_test .
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is If we have any other folders or nested folders and files present in the same directory. Then this is happening and resolution is either to add .dockerignorefile or just move it to a folder and then move to that folder from command prompt and then execute docker build command.

Comment: This helped me. My problem was I mapped all directory where Dockerfile was in the docker-compose.yml file (in volume section).
When large node repository was inside this caused really slow building. However simply adding this folder to .dockerignore didn't worked. Thanks for idea ;)